# How to subscribe to YouTube comments?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to subscribe to YouTube comments under a particular video?
I only see how to subscribe to the whole channel of a particular user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

YouTube comments are for free - there is no need to subscribe to them, you either see them (and can comment) or you don't (when YouTuber who uploaded video disabled them on his video). The third case can be if you have some extension which hides YouTube comments with or without your consent.