# Is it possible to get notifications for new comments on a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, notifications

Suppose that there is a video on YouTube which is not on my channel, but published by somebody else.

Is there some way in which I can subscribe to get the notifications about new comments on that particular video?

---

One use case I can imagine: Many teachers now use YouTube to publish videos with their lectures. And both the students and the teacher might be interested to see new comments. (And in many cases the YouTube channel is not the channel created by the teacher - it might be a channel of the school/department/university. So it's a bit different from setting up notifications about new activity on *my own* videos.)

---

<sup>*Note.* I have seen that there is already this question: [How to subscribe to YouTube comments?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124039) From the formulation of the question it seems that this question might be considered a duplicate of that one. However, the accepted answer answers the question as if the word *subscribe* was meant as *pay for a subscription*. (I am not sure whether this is what the asker intended, but that is the answer they've accepted.) Therefore I opted for a new question rather than a bounty on the old one - since to some extent, the offered bounty would be asking for something different from the already accepted answer.</sup>

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 7 times. Please be specific about the type of solution to get a notification for new comments you are looking for, i.e., if you are asking to use the built-in notifications, please make it clear. Please remember that questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic, they might be asked in [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Each page has a total number of comments.  The comment field number is tagged using CSS so you could use a solution to check the page periodically and compare that tagged number to a stored variable.to see if it has changed.

If you have an android cell phone you could use Tasker to periodically run a task to check that for you and notify you in the manner of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a way, outside of being able to access the account/channel itself, or typing a comment to each chain so that you can manually check.

In short, no, I'm sorry.